# Vertically align "after" element that contains icon

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu, and the first item replaces the content with an icon. I'm doing this by setting the `font-size` to `0px` of the main element, and then adding an after element. This seems to be a common practice and it works so far so good.

However I can't seem to align the after element with the rest of the navigation menu.

I started playing around with `line-height` and `vertical-align` which got me closer to my goal, but as you can see, it's still not properly working as expected.

The fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/67dyxLr1/

```
<nav class="nav-primary">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.nav-primary {
  background: #CCC;
}

.nav-primary li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.nav-primary a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 32px 20px;
  border: 1px dashed black; /* border only used for display purpose of alignment*/
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.nav-primary a:hover {
    background: #FFF;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {

}

.home a {
  font-size:0px;
}

.home a:after {
  font-family: "dashicons";
  content: " \f102";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You need to add `overflow:hidden` to your main menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: middle` to your `li`

**CSS**

```
.nav-primary li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/67dyxLr1/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add vertical align to your li:

```css
.nav-primary {
  background: #CCC;
}
.nav-primary li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* add this */
}
.nav-primary a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 32px 20px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  /* border only used for display purpose of alignment*/
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.nav-primary a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item {} .home a {
  font-size: 0px;
}
.home a:after {
  font-family: "dashicons";
  content: " \f102";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-primary">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah, Great! Thank you so much. Such a simple solution.